# ajax causing fadeToggle to run multiple times

Tags: jquery, ajax

as the title says on my application there is a ajax .load function that is causing a fadeToggle to play up.

The app works as follows:

there is a jquery function that loads the "events" page:

`

```
function LOAD_EVENTS_PAGE(d,m,y)
{
  $('.show_page').load('events.php',function(){
    scroll_bar=$('.cndr_sidebar_inner').jScrollPane({mouseWheelSpeed:30,autoReinitialise:true,maintainPosition:false,animateScroll:true}).data('jsp');
    //RELOAD FORM INPUT CODE
    $(".form-field").length&&(wtextval=[],$(".form-field").each(function(a){var b=$(this).attr("id");if(""==b||null==b||void 0==b)b="form-field_"+a,$(this).attr("id","form-field_"+a);wtextval[b]=$(this).val();$(this).addClass("watermark");$(".form-field").css("color","#999")}),$(document).on("focus",".form-field",function(a){a=$(this).attr("id");$(this).val()==wtextval[a]&&($(this).val("").removeClass("watermark"),$(".form-field").css("color","#333"))}),$(document).on("blur",".form-field",function(a){a=$(this).attr("id");""==$(this).val()&&($(this).val(wtextval[a]).addClass("watermark"),$(".form-field").css("color","#999"))}));
    $(".cndr_but_2, #cancel_but_2, #accept_but_2").click(function() {
      var d = $('#date_holder').attr('value');
      var m = $('#date_holder').attr('name');
      var y = $('#date_holder').attr('alt');
      $(".datepicker_popup_2").fadeToggle( "fast", "linear" );
      var d = $('#date_holder').attr('value', d);
      var m = $('#date_holder').attr('name', m);
      var y = $('#date_holder').attr('alt', y);
    });
    $('.event_date').attr('value',d+'-'+m+'-'+y);
    $('.show_header_date').text(GET_MONTH(m)+' '+y);
    $('.day_field_2').val(d);
    $('.month_field_2').val(m);
    $('.year_field_2').val(y);
  });
}
```

`

the toggle part if you dont wanna keep searching through that code:

`$(".datepicker_popup_2").fadeToggle( "fast", "linear" );`

Now, the problem is when the user uses the function more than ones, after a bit of playing around I found that it must be switching the toggle or adding on to it type of thing, I am just very confused by this, but basically the "fadeToggle" is on a full page pop up (basically a date picker type thing) and if i visit the events page a second time and click on the link which opens up the date picker, when i try to close it it fades out but then fades back in again......but, i found that if i open up the page a third time it fades out then fades back in , then...fades back out hence why i said it must be "adding onto" the toggle command?????

so my questions are:

1) what is causing this?
2) how can I fix this?
3) is there a css fade toggle i can use instead?

Comment: Please format your code in a readable manner first.

Comment: It's very difficult to read through that code to fully understand it and will take too long, but it sounds like it's creating multiple instances and firing each instance every time you initiate the function. You should create an attribute in your HTML (HTML5), set it to "0" and when the function is initialised the first time, set that attribute to "1" for example so it eliminates duplications.

Comment: so what your saying is i could set up a attribute such as value="0", then when the code runs the first time change the .val to 1 in jquery then the second time it runs through the if statement it will not run toggle?

Comment: i resolved the issue by adding: `.unbind("click", handler);` to the the fadeToggle

Comment: what jQuery version are you using? .. the load() shorthand method  is depreciated since version 1.8 and will be removed from jQuery soon.. also do you have a jsfiddle  or codepen example?